# How to create a column following multicolumn conditions? pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe in PySpark, similar to this:

```
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|id |date_lead  |date_login |date_access|date_buy   |date_del   |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|1  |01-01-2022 |null       |null       |null       |null       |
|2  |02-01-2022 |02-01-2022 |null       |null       |null       |
|3  |03-01-2022 |03-01-2022 |03-01-2022 |null       |null       |
|4  |04-01-2022 |04-01-2022 |04-01-2022 |04-01-2022 |null       |
|5  |05-01-2022 |05-01-2022 |05-01-2022 |05-01-2022 |05-01-2022 |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I would like to create a column to measure this funnel.
Where the value of this new column would be according to the last non-null value of the columns in question.

Expected output:

```
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|id |date_lead  |date_login |date_access|date_buy   |date_del   |step       |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|1  |01-01-2022 |null       |null       |null       |null       |lead       |
|2  |02-01-2022 |02-01-2022 |null       |null       |null       |login      |
|3  |03-01-2022 |03-01-2022 |03-01-2022 |null       |null       |access     |
|4  |04-01-2022 |04-01-2022 |04-01-2022 |04-01-2022 |null       |buy        |
|5  |05-01-2022 |05-01-2022 |05-01-2022 |05-01-2022 |05-01-2022 |del        |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

In python, I would use the loc[ ] method, like this:

```py
df.loc[~df['date_lead'].isna(), 'step'] = 'lead'
```

And it would go through the other columns.

In python it overrides the value of the previous condition, however, I didn't find anything similar in pyspark in my searches.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I believe your `pandas` version can't achieve the goal that you want, since you only check if `date_lead` is `null` or not to determine the value in `step`. In fact, all row will be assigned to the `lead` value.

If you want to achieve your goal in `spark`, you can use `.when()`, that is:

```
lead_condition = func.col('date_lead').isNotNull() & func.col('date_login').isNull() & func.col('date_access').isNull() & func.col('date_buy').isNull() & func.col('date_del').isNull()
login_condition = func.col('date_lead').isNotNull() & func.col('date_login').isNotNull() & func.col('date_access').isNull() & func.col('date_buy').isNull() & func.col('date_del').isNull()
...

df.withColumn('step', func.when(lead_condition, func.lit('lead'))
                          .when(login_condition, func.lit('login'))
                          ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup and Spark solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,3,4,5],
                   "date_lead": ["01-01-2022", "02-01-2022", "03-01-2022", "04-01-2022", "05-01-2022"],
                   "date_login": [None, "02-01-2022", "03-01-2022", "04-01-2022", "05-01-2022"],
                   "date_access": [None, None, "03-01-2022", "04-01-2022", "05-01-2022"],
                   "date_buy": [None, None, None, "04-01-2022", "05-01-2022"],
                   "date_del": [None, None, None, None, "05-01-2022"]})

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)

from pyspark.sql.functions import when
sdf.withColumn("step", when(sdf.date_login.isNull(),"lead")
                       .when(sdf.date_access.isNull(),"login")
                       .when(sdf.date_buy.isNull(),"access")
                       .when(sdf.date_del.isNull(),"buy")
                       .otherwise("del")).show()
```

If you already have Pandas logic defined, you can use [Fugue](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue/) to map it across partitions:

```py
def logic(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df.loc[~df['date_lead'].isna(), 'step'] = 'lead'
    df.loc[~df['date_login'].isna(), 'step'] = 'login'
    df.loc[~df['date_access'].isna(), 'step'] = 'access'
    df.loc[~df['date_buy'].isna(), 'step'] = 'buy'
    df.loc[~df['date_del'].isna(), 'step'] = 'del'
    return df

from fugue import transform
transform(sdf, logic, schema="*,step:str",engine=spark).show()
```

Output for both:

```
+---+----------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+------+
| id| date_lead|date_login|date_access|  date_buy|  date_del|  step|
+---+----------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+------+
|  1|01-01-2022|      null|       null|      null|      null|  lead|
|  2|02-01-2022|02-01-2022|       null|      null|      null| login|
|  3|03-01-2022|03-01-2022| 03-01-2022|      null|      null|access|
|  4|04-01-2022|04-01-2022| 04-01-2022|04-01-2022|      null|   buy|
|  5|05-01-2022|05-01-2022| 05-01-2022|05-01-2022|05-01-2022|   del|
+---+----------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+------+
```